# Scraping SpeechesUSA.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the title links of speeches-usa.com. The following is my Python code:

```
SPEECH_SOURCE = 'http://www.speeches-usa.com/'
def get_speeches():
        cj = CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        p = opener.open(SPEECH_SOURCE)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(p.read(), PARSER_TYPE)
        info = soup.find_all('a', class_='ListText')
        elements = []
        for element in info:
            elements.append(element)
        for i in x range(0, min(len(elements), 5)):
            print elements[i]
```

(1) I'm not sure what to put in soup.find_all() argument to get the links - I tried putting elements.append(element.get_text()) but that gives the following instead, which takes away the links

```
John Adams - Inaugural
        Address

Samuel Adams - American
        Independence

Spiro Agnew - Television
        News Coverage

Susan B. Anthony - Women's
        Right to Vote
```

(2) The results seem incomplete, for example, we are missing Jane Adams in the code below.

```
<a class="ListText" href="Transcripts/john_adams-inaugural.html">John Adams - Inaugural
        Address<br/>
</a>
0
<a class="ListText" href="Transcripts/samuel_adams-independence.html">Samuel Adams - American
        Independence<br/>
</a>
1
<a class="ListText" href="Transcripts/spiro_agnew-networknews.html">Spiro Agnew - Television
        News Coverage<br/>
</a>
2
<a class="ListText" href="Transcripts/susan_b_anthony-vote.html">Susan B. Anthony - Women's
        Right to Vote</a>
3
<a class="ListText" href="Transcripts/spiro_agnew-networknews.html"></a>
4
```

Help and direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: This code is not executable - please post a usable example, including relevant imports and variables (e.g. `SPEECH_SOURCE`)

Comment: Edited! Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should give you full URLs:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse


def get_speeches(input_url):
    p = urllib2.urlopen(input_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')
    info = soup.find_all('a', class_='ListText')

    for element in info:
        print urlparse.urljoin(input_url, element['href'])

SOURCE_URL = 'http://speeches-usa.com'
get_speeches(SOURCE_URL)
```

`element.get_text()` does exactly what it says - it gets the text of the element. If you want a property, you can use square brackets, as in `element['href']`

EDIT: the comment below fairly pointed out that this misses some elements as not all links have the `ListText` class. The following code instead finds all links, checks if `'Transcripts'` is in the link provided (I'm assuming it's the links to transcripts that you need), and appends it to a list if so. This can feature duplicates, hence `set()` is used to print only the unique entries.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse


def get_speeches(input_url):
    p = urllib2.urlopen(url=input_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')
    info = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

    all_transcripts = list()

    for element in info:
        if 'Transcripts' in element['href']:
            all_transcripts.append(urlparse.urljoin(input_url, element['href']))

    for transcript_url in set(all_transcripts):
        print transcript_url

SOURCE_URL = 'http://speeches-usa.com'
get_speeches(SOURCE_URL)
```

Comment: @宏杰李 you're right that it misses some links - I've edited ot try and improve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bs4, requests
r = requests.get('http://speeches-usa.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

a_tags = soup.find('table', width="925").find_all('a', text=True, href=re.compile('\.html'))
for a in a_tags:  
    link = a.get('href')
    text = a.get_text(strip=True).replace('\n        ', '')
    print(link, text, sep="\t\t")
```

out:

```
Transcripts/susan_b_anthony-vote.html       Susan B. Anthony - Women'sRight to Vote
Transcripts/albert_beveridge-question.html      Albert J. Beveridge - ThePhillipine Question
Transcripts/william_jennings_bryan-cross.html       William Jennings Bryan - Crossof Gold
Transcripts/william_jennings_bryan-19002.html       William Jennings Bryan - 1900Democratic Presidential Acceptance
Transcripts/tony_blair-irish.html       Tony Blair - Addressto Irish Parliament
Transcripts/napolean_bonaparte-farewell.html        Napolean Bonaparte - Farewell to the Old Guard
Transcripts/sarah_brady-1996dnc.html        Sarah Brady - 1996DNC Keynote address
Transcripts/pat_buchanan-citadel.html       Pat Buchannan - Arepublic not an Empire
Transcripts/edmund_burke.html       Edumund Burke - Thedeath of Marie Antoinette
Transcripts/barbara_bush-1992rnc.html       Barbara Bush - 1992RNC Speech
Transcripts/barbara_bush-wellesley.html     Barbara Bush - WelleslyCollege
Transcripts/george_bush-somalia.html        George Bush - Conditionsin Somalia
Transcripts/george_bush-1991sou.html        George Bush - 1991State of the Union
Transcripts/george_bush-saudi.html      George Bush - Defenseof Saudi Arabia
Transcripts/george_w_bush-knoxville.html        George W. Bush - Anew approach
Transcripts/stokeley_carmichael-going.html      Stokley Carmichael - BlackPower
Transcripts/stokeley_carmichael-weaint.html     Stokley Carmichael - "Weain't goin'"
Transcripts/jimmy_carter-energy.html        Jimmy Carter - EnergyCrisis
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```